# Comedy Manhwa where FL reincarnates in her favourite novel and breaks engagement with ML to survive

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I can't remember the name of this manwha that I read a while ago. The FL reincarnated as the villainess of her favorite game/novel (I can't remember). The story happens in a school, and the characters are teenagers. In the original ending of the story, her character died cause she did something to the FL of her favorite's story. So, to avoid that, she acts like a good person and break her engagement with the prince (I think it was a prince) and wants to see the love between the ML and the FL of the original story. But the ML fall in love with the protagonist. If I remember correctly, the antagonist was a girl with short red hair and was from a family that used to be rich but lost all their money in gambling (could be wrong about how they lost it, but she was bullied because she was a noblewoman and now she's poor). In a scene the protagonist gives her a dress to go to the ball where (according to the novel) she is supposed to fall in love with the ML. The protagonist's family were florists. In the end, the antagonist ends up with a professor of her school after a time skip. I think the ML was blonde and the protagonist too, but could be wrong cause I read a lot of manwha and maybe I'm thinking about other characters, lol I remember a lot of details but not the name, help :(

ETA: She was top of her class and the antagonist was jealous about it. In the original novel, the girl with red hair was top of her class. Also, in a scene the protagonist make flower arrangements for the ball, and everyone is amazed at how beautiful the decorations were. There is a professor/headmaster of the school that hates the protagonist and is trying to help the antagonist bc she couldn't tolerate the idea of someone that isn't from noble blood to get married to the prince, or something like that (the protagonist wasn't from a noble family I think, she was rich bc her family business was a success iirc)

ETA2: I remember this manwha as a comedy!

Answer (score 2):

This is [The Male Lead's Girl Friend](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-male-leads-girl-friend)

You already remember all the key points of the story, but here is the synopsis anyways:

> Waking up inside your favorite novel sounds like a dream come true. Unless you’re born as the hated villainess, that is. Our new, full-fledged Louise Sweeny must try to reinvent her character to dodge her doomed fate of being killed off at the end of the story. It seemed easy enough at first, but there’s one big problem. The story, which she knew like the back of her hand, has veered so far off course that she can’t predict what plot twists are coming next. Can she avoid getting in the way of the male and female leads’ romance to save herself from impending demise?